# Searchable drop down list html

Tags: html, ajax

I have this code for a searchable drop down list in html. The html is working fine but searching in drop down list is not working .  I've tried to find the error but I'm going wrong. Please help me correct my code.
Thanks.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Bootstrap-select example</h2>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
    <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
    <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
    <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used this version of bootstrap for my project. Try this.

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Bootstrap-select example</h2>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
    <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
    <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
    <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
  </select>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: But still search bar missing in drop down list list when i open drop down list

Comment: After clicking on the dropdown button, when the drop-down list is shown. Start Typing. Then the search bar will appear.